# Type 'ReactI18NextChildren | Iterable<ReactI18NextChildren>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am following this [link](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) to implement react material `Autocomplete`.

I am using the `renderInput` the same way it is described in the documentation

```
renderInput={(params: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) => (
            <TextField
                {...params}
                placeholder="Sections"
                label='Nil Sections'
            />
        )}
```

But I am getting this error on `TextField`

```
Type '{ placeholder: string; label: string; id: string; disabled: boolean; fullWidth: boolean; size: "small" | undefined; InputLabelProps: Omit<HTMLAttributes<HTMLLabelElement>, "color">; InputProps: { ...; }; inputProps: InputHTMLAttributes<...> & { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Omit<FilledTextFieldProps | OutlinedTextFieldProps | StandardTextFieldProps, "variant">'.
  The types of 'InputLabelProps.children' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'ReactI18NextChildren | Iterable<ReactI18NextChildren>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
      Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
        Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': children, type, props, key
```

Full error is this

[image]

And I know exactly which line is causing it, this is line that is causing it, because when I remove it from `TextField` the error goes away but then the `Autocomplete` doesn't work

```
{...params}
```

I am not sure why is it causing any problem, I am following the documentation as it is and not changing anything.

I am getting the error is saying that the type it expects is not what it is returning because of the `AutocompleteRenderInputParams`, these properties it does not expect in the render tag control but if we do not give these properties it does not even work.

Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the solution.

So what I tried is, rather than adding the whole `params` I started adding the params one by one and till this point it started working perfectly.

So I replaced these from `params` and it works like a charm now

```
id={params.id}                                           
inputProps={params.inputProps}                                                       
InputProps={params.InputProps}
```

By approaching this way, I could also find out which exact param was causing the issue, so for my case this was the param that was causing the issue

```
InputLabelProps={params.InputLabelProps}
```